# Android not playing HTML5 video on HTTPS

Tags: android, video, html, https

I am using HTML5  element to play a sample.mp4. It plays fine if using HTTP protocol. If I change the URL to use HTTPS, it will give error "Sorry, this video cannot be played." The SSL certificate is valid. I have tried on both IIS and Apache server.

```
<video src="sample.mp4" id="myvideo" />
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('myvideo').play();">Play</a>
```

Comment: What's the site and what version of Android?  I know Android had problems with certain certificates like wildcard certs and SAN certs.

Comment: I have tried Android 2.1 and 2.2 on three different Android devices. I have tried with Equifax Certificate on IIS and DigiCert Certificate on Apache. Android displays Web pages OK using HTTPS, but not video.

Comment: By the way, self-assigned certificate on Apache also tested. Same error.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like Android does not currently support serving video from a SSL (https) link: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/7e7003b845c3fb98

Comment: Yes, I found out the same link and quit seeking further for the solution. It is weird that there is no official documentation about this. Thanks.

Comment: It's mentioned in the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html): "HTTPS is not supported before Android 3.1"

Answer (score 0):

Android will support https audio/video playback as per the developer site:

http/https live streaming draft protocol:
mpeg-2 ts media files only
Android 3 and 4 and above; NOT supported before Android 3.0

Comment: Do you have a source/link for that?

Comment: Nevermind, already found it: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html